# SQL messages are not being logged to development.log in app upgraded from Rails 2.3 -> 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am in the process of upgrading an old Rails 2.3 app (and in fact it was even older...) to Rails 3.2, and my SQL statements are not being logged to development.log. A Rails 3.1 app I have on my computer is logging its SQL statements just fine.

I am using pow to serve the app locally. If I run rails server, the SQL is output, but that's because the SQL statements are being output to STDERR. I checked what logger ActiveRecord is using (`logger.info ActiveRecord::Base.logger.inspect`) and I get:

```
#<Logger:0x007fdb9f788688 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007fdb9f788638 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007fdb9f788548 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007fdb9f7885e8 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDERR>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007fdb9f7885c0 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007fdb9f788570>>>>
```

As you can see, LogDevice's @dev points to STDERR. In my Rails 3.1 app the same query gets:

```
#<ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger:0x106f28c10 @guard=#<Mutex:0x106ec21b8>, @level=0, @auto_flushing=1, @buffer={}, @log=#<File:/web/unique/dynamic_coupons/log/development.log>>
```

There is nothing interesting in my configuration — it's all pretty standard — but I'm including them below for posterity.

Something somewhere has turned my SQL logging off, and I can't fathom why. I'm hoping that I can add a config line somewhere to force ActiveRecord logging to go to development.log again.

Thank you for your help!

#### development.rb

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for ActiveRecord models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Mailer configuration
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'lta.dev' }
end
```

#### application.rb

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    # config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone who responded and thought about this. It turns out that there was a library from the 2.x days that hijacked the logger (innocently enough). I wasn't aware of this library because another programmer added it. I happened to discover it today when I did a search for 'Logger.new' and I saw what was going on.

Comment: Hi pauldoerwald, can you give me more details on it? We recently upgraded from 2.3 to 3.1 and we encounter the same problem. I'm hoping your input would help us resolve the problem or at least put us in the right direction..

Comment: For me it was the Spawn gem/plugin that was overriding the definition of Logger. As soon as I removed Spawn, logging started working correctly again. Of course YMMV, but if you search for "Logger.new" in your source code, and perhaps through your gems, you might find the offending statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you start console (development env), what's the output of Rails.configuration.log_level?

Now compare ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level to Logger::DEBUG (0), Logger::INFO (1), Logger::WARN (2), and Logger::ERROR (3).

If ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level is lower than Rails.configuration.log_level, then development.log will not contain any SQL logging from ActiveRecord.